# Fetching image from backend

Tags: react-native

I fetched data from backend and the images don't show !!! 
item.text and everything got ,,,expect image why??

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      let data = await fetch("http://192.168.6.107:8080/fashion");
      let res = await data.json();
      this.setState({
        post: res
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.post.results.map((item, key) => (
          <View key={key}>
            <Text>{item.username}</Text>
            <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            <Image
              source={{uri:`http://192.168.6.107:8080/${item.images_name}`}}
              style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
            />

          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you try to log `http://192.168.6.107:8080/${item.images_name}` and check if it is a workable link?

Comment: No,how can i do that?? on the other hand if the link works the image will be showed !!

Comment: @amanirose Do `console.log("Image url", 'http://192.168.6.107:8080/${item.images_name}')` and see in the console if the link is valid.

Comment: I followed the link of the images and i see it,,,but i don't know why the images don't display on screen !!?? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log your image URLs like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.post.results.map((item, key) => {
          console.log('image url - ', `http://192.168.6.107:8080/${item.images_name}`)
          return (
            <View key={key}>
              <Text>{item.username}</Text>
              <Text>{item.text}</Text>
              <Image
                source={{ uri: `http://192.168.6.107:8080/${item.images_name}` }}
                style={{
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I followed the link of the images and i see it,,,but i don't know why the images don't display on screen !!??

Comment: @amanirose try to replace your url with some another, for example - `https://placeimg.com/640/480/any` and check if it will render image

Comment: I changed the uri  to  this one  uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png" and also didn't work

Comment: @amanirose I suppose something wrong with your styling. Can you create a reproduction of your problem on https://snack.expo.io/ ? So I can have a look.

Comment: I don't think the reason is because of the styling because i run in a new folder expo int image--and put this code   <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
        />---and also did't work !!! what should i do??

Comment: @amanirose I've just tried your code it works on iOS/Android/Web, take a look https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/image-sample

Comment: yes ,,Finally it work i just install npm install -g expo-cli and then the images show

Comment: Thank you really for your time , i  appreciated that